# AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'list_packages' - AWS EMR Notebook

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

I am trying to install a new package in AWS EMR Notebook and running into the error "AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'list_packages'". However, this seems to be the [official approach](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/install-python-libraries-on-a-running-cluster-with-emr-notebooks/). Appreciate your help in finding what I am missing

**Code**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Window
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc =SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sc.list_packages()
```

**Config**
emr-5.20.0
Spark 2.4.0

Comment: Are you using EMR notebook?

Comment: yes, updated the question for clarity

Comment: When you start EMR notebook and choose PySpark, you should be already have SparkContenxt, have you tried just running `sc.list_packages()` without anything else?

Comment: running only sc.list_packages() throws same error. Same error for sc.deployMode. However I am able to run spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll() ,sc.appName and sc.master succesfully

Comment: have you chosen the pyspark environment or python environment when you created EMR notebook. If it is pyspark then it would work but if it is python than it won't work.